# How to add custom made object to a 2D array of the same type

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

```
public static boolean[][] random(int[][] grid) {
    boolean[][] a = new boolean[20][20];
    for (int i = 0; i < grid1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid1.length; j++) {
            Cell[] cellArray = null;
            if (grid1[i][j] == 0) {
                a[i][j] = false;                   
            } else if (grid1[i][j] == 1) {
                a[i][j] = false;
                Cell cell = new Cell(i, j, 1);
            } else if (grid1[i][j] == 3) {
                a[i][j] = false;
                Cell cell = new Cell(i, j, 3);
            } else if (grid1[i][j] == 4) {
                a[i][j] = true;
                Cell cell = new Cell(i, j, 4);
            } else if (grid1[i][j] == 5) {
                a[i][j] = false;
            }

        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

I'm trying to add Cell objects to my int grid using their value inside the program. I have declared a `Cell[][] cellGrid = new Cell[20][20]` inside my class i want to add Cell objects to that grid. But it should be same as the `int[][] grid`. Can someone help with this.

Comment: Please don't name your variable `a`.

Comment: Can you please explain "I'm trying to add Cell objects to my int grid using their value". Obviously you can store `Cell` objects in an `int` grid so do you mean add an integer field of a `Cell` to the `int[][]` variable?

Comment: "i want to add Cell objects to that grid. But it should be same as the int[][] grid" --> Do you want to add value of int[][] grid to cell object? Can u also post the Cell class?

Comment: class Cell {

    int x, y; // coordinates
    double gCost = 0; // G : distance from starting point
    double heuristicCost = 0; // H : distance to end point (approximate)
    double finalCost = 0; // F = G + H
    Cell parent; // cell, visited before the current cell
    int weight;

    Cell(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

Comment: public Cell(int x, int y, int weight) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

Comment: @ArMD I want to create a seperate Cell type 2d array same as my int 2d array.

Comment: Thanks i have figured a way to do thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Cell[][] grid= new Cell[20][20];
for(int i=0;i<grid.length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<grid.length;j++){   
       int temp= integer_array[i][j];
       grid[i][j]= new Cell(temp);

       //grid[i][j] will be an object of Cell class and any member of the class 
       //can be called 
    }
}
System.out.println(grid[0][1].data);
```

Comment: It's bit harder in this way i tried this way but i need a shorter code for this :(

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you asked to use `int[][] grid` as element. In Java, it is not possible to perform *operator overloading*. So '[]' cannot be tailored specifically to a cell element, derived from the primitive type `int`. The functionality you asked for can in Java only be achieved by defining a class and using class methods for addressing the element `i,j`, i.e. `setElement(int x, int y, boolean value)` and `getElement(int x, int y)`. In C++, operator overloading can be performed. However, this in some cases led to difficult-to-read code, and so this option was omitted in Java.

In Java it is also not possible to extend a primitive type `int`, as well as the autoboxed class `Integer`.